# assigned css class doesn't work when assigned from variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm dynamically creating html element inside page
and I'm bounding events on this dynamic elements like

```
$('#fields').on('input', '.myClass', function (e) {

});
```

and inside js code I'm injecting element like (this works with hardcoded css class)

```
'<tr><td><input id='+myObj.id + ' class="form-control myClass" type="text" value='+myObj.Value +' name="somename"></td></tr>'
```

but when I change code with css class name from variable it doesn't work

```
var cssClass= "form-control myClass";
'<tr><td><input id='+myObj.id + ' class='+cssClass +'type="text" value='+myObj.Value +' name="somename"></td></tr>'
```

Answer (score 7):

> ```
> class="form-control myClass"
> ```

In your original code, the attribute has quotes around it

> ```
> class='+cssClass +'type="text"
> ```

In your new code, the quotes are no longer part of the string.

Since the value of the string variable includes *spaces*, it is not treated as a *single* attribute value. Don't forget your quotes.

---

Smashing strings together to form HTML is error prone and hard to debug. Don't do it.

Building up the data structure with DOM or jQuery makes for more verbose, but much more readable code. As a bonus, you don't need to worry about special characters (like spaces, `&` or `"`) as they'll be encoded correctly automatically.

```
var myObj = { Value: 123 };
var row = $("<tr />").append(
    $("<td />").append(
        $("<input />")
            .attr("id", myObj.id)
            .addClass("form-control")
            .addClass("myClass")
            .attr("type", "text")
            .val(myObj.Value)
            .attr("name", "somename")
    )
);
console.log(row[0]);
```